# Как настроить ширину экрана при которой появляеться гамбургер меню(Wordpress шаблон I-craft)

Tags: wordpress, меню, адаптивность

Доброго времени суток. На wordpress на шаблоне i-craft при уменьшении экрана появляеться гамбургер меню. Но он появляеться при разрешении 1024px. Где я могу это исправить чтобы гамбургер появлялся при 750px.

[Ссылка на сайт](http://avto.fof.com.ua/)

я так понимаю что это нужно менять в /wp-content/themes/i-craft/js/functions.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гамбургер появляется при ширине от 0 до 1069px.

Исправьте style.css  в строке 4516.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо. А где настраивается способ отображения? Сейчас выдвигается колонка слева при этом сжимая контент, а нужно настроить чтобы выдвигалась вниз при этом в самой шапке сайта.

Comment: вы для начала этому menu-toggle поставьте `z-index:1;` а то на него не нажать

Comment: и это уже другой вопрос. Если ответ на данный вопрос полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.